# Application Architecture: Individual Oracle Accounts

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, authentication, architecture

I have been working in a small shop which has been running VB6 for its main application. I started there about six years ago. In my previous experience I've only ever dealt with MSSQL. This shop primarily uses Oracle. Since iv'e been there I've mostly worked in .NET. I've even managed to slowly integrate some semblance of order by introducing CSLA framework even though my colleague knows nothing about OOD or OOA as he's been working in VB6 and has been consumed by it as well as managing the database.

One of the most annoying observations is that my colleague insists on creating a unique account for each every user who needs access to the database. There is also a separate table which provides in depth detail of the users access rights. In order to utilize connection pooling I created a unique authentication piece which authenticates the user against Oracle and then stores the user rights in the Principal/Identity. I then use a common account which then facilitates the normal routine communication with database.

Since implementing this I've noticed a decrease in TNS errors.

Does anyone see any conflict with this approach?

Comment: I wonder about a few things -
1. if you hit your database with a common user account, I hope that you are applying appropriate logic for audit tracking, tracing which user is doing what ?



2. Also, If you guys are creating multiple users, I hope you are paying oracle by cpus and not by user accounts. Else, you're readying  yourselves for heavy licensing fees payout..

Comment: @learn4living - Thankfully I don't have to manage the database. With respect to auditing nearly every table that is modified has a user name associated with it. I simply get the account name from the authenticated user and update accordingly.